# Virtual Machines running out of memory on server

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization, vdi

Several of the datastores that user's virtual desktops reside are out of space to grow the virtual machine disks. The VMs do not have room to grow and users are beginning to not be able to even login to these virtual desktops.

Soon, all VMs on that datastore will have the same issue. Soon, VMs on the other datastores will have the same issue.

The only way I know to resolve this issue is to refresh the VMs on the datastores that are out of space. But this would mean all the configuration that users have done on their machines will be lost!

What else can be done?
Also can the number of virtual machines that are being created in a datastore be limited to a given maximum, say only 15 virtual desktops will be created on this datastore at max? This sounds like a single line of code but I don't knw where and how?

Answer (score 1):

In such a situation it is advisable to use nfs or shared storage for providing space to VMs.
In my case , i mounted external storage on Dom0 (datastores in your case) using nfs and then passed on the storage to virtual machines using "xm block-attach". Using xm block-attach you can assign additional vbd(virtual block devices) to your VMs without making them to stop/pause. These vbd can be used by the VMs after creating required file system on the them.

For assigning memory to VMs,you can use "xm mem-set" (assuming your hypervisor finds spare memory to allocate).If you are using xen , it can be verified using xm list command.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try. For future, I am trying to move to shared storage.